# Analysing the performance of forecasting models

Tags: forecasting

I am just getting into studying forecasting methods and I want to figure out how performance is commonly measured.  My instinct is that out-of-sample performance is most important (you want to see how well your model does with unseen data).  I have also noticed that forecast performance does not do well if your out-of-sample data is too large (which makes sense the farther you go in the future, the less likely your model will perform well).  So I was wondering how to determine the best size of out-of-sample data to test on?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the domain ? I mean the kind of phenomena you are trying to forecast (e.g., weather, arrival of customer etc.)

Comment: Test on typical usage scenarios.  When I was developing a forecasting system for the electrical grid, we had specific tests for short-term (1-6 hour), medium-term (6-48 hour), long-term (2-7 days) and extended (7-14 days), all of which matched different operational data requirements.  Each forecasting bracket had different metrics for what was considered "good" based on who was going to be using the data for what purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the forecasting horizon with the out-of-sample data to test on the forecasting performance, when you say " I have also noticed that forecast performance does not do well if your out-of-sample data is too large".
When you do forecasting, you are usually interested in a certain forecasting horizon. For example, if you have a time series at monthly frequency, you might be interested in one month horizon (short-term forecast) or 12 months (long-term forecasting). So the forecasting performance usually deteriorates with longer forecasting horizons, not with more out-of-sample data.
It is hard to suggest the number of observations on which you test your model because it depends on how you want to evaluate the forecast. If you want to use some formal statistical tests, then you need more observations, but if you are interested in predicting a certain event and you are just interest in the performance of a single model, then you are fine with a relatively low number of out-of-sample observations.
Hope this helps,
Paolo